# Inspecting Dask graph submitted for computing

Tags: dask

It's certainly possible to view a Dask graph at any stage while holding onto the object. Though once `.compute()` is called on a Dask object, there is an opportunity to apply additional optimizations to the Dask graph before running the computation. Any optimizations applied at this stage would impact how the computation is run. However this optimized graph would not necessarily be attached to a corresponding Dask object available to the user. Is there a way to also view the final Dask graph that was actually used for the computation?

Answer (score 0):

The graph is not easily accessible after it has been submitted.

If you are using the distributed scheduler you can inspect the state there after submission, but it is no longer in a form that matches the traditional graph specification.

The best option I can think of is to optimize the graph before computing, and to investigate this.  This isn't guaranteed to be exactly the same, but is likely close.

Comment: How does one "optimize the graph before computing"?

Comment: Appropriate optimizations are run automatically when you call compute.  If you want to call these separately then use dask.optimize.  See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/optimize.html and http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.optimize